# Triple integral in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $R$ be the region in the first octant bounded by a surface $F(x,y,z) = 0$ and the
coordinate planes.  The
projection of $R$

1. on the $xy$-plane is bounded by the coordinates axes and the curve $y = 9 - x^2$ ,
2. on the $xz$-plane is bounded by the coordinates axes and
   the curve $x =\sqrt{9-z}$.
3. on the $yz$-plane is bounded by the coordinates axes and
   the curve $z=9-y$.

Now, the volume of the region $R$ is asked. When I sketch the region, I get $1/8$ of a sphere cutted by the plane $z=9-y$. Then, I write a triple integral as follows. $$\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{9-z}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-z}}dx \, dy \, dz$$

However, the solution says the inner integral has bounds $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-y-z}} dx .$$ What is the part that I am missing?

Comment: If I understand the region correctly, neither integrals seem correct. You will have to split the region into two sub-regions at $y = z$.

Comment: I agree with MathLover. This is a challenging question because we're not given actual equations of surfaces that determine the region. The upper bound on $x$ should be the *smaller* of $\sqrt{9-z}$ and $\sqrt{9-y}$. Where they got $\sqrt{9-y-z}$ is ... a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y=9-x^2$, $z=9-x^2$ and $y+z=9$. So, the region $R$ is symmetric with respect to the plane $z=y$, which allows the volume integration to be set up as follows
$$V=2\int_0^{\frac92}dz \int_z^{9-z}dy \int_0^{\sqrt{9-y}}dx
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not get it why the correct answer is as above, unfortunately.